# inotifywait invalid option -d (daemon)

Tags: inotify

I'm trying to run inotifywait as daemon by this command:

```
root@server:/# inotifywait -mrd -e delete -e delete_self -e create -e moved_from -e moved_to /path -o /tmp/path.log
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
inotifywait: invalid option -- 'd'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't cross-post with serverfault, it is evil! After your question was (unfairly) closed there, or you didn't get useful answers, is it ok to re-post. But only after that.

Comment: Crosspost:http://serverfault.com/questions/677345/inotifywait-invalid-option-d-daemon

Comment: Don't provide `-m` with `-d` as it's implied. With `-d` you must provide `-o {logfile}`.

Comment: @roaima This is whole command I use: `inotifywait -rd -e delete -e delete_self -e create -e moved_from -e moved_to /tmp -o /tmp/path.log` and unfortunately still doesn't work.

Comment: Your command works for me. I'm running version 3.14 as given by `inotifywait -h`. I would assume, therefore, that you're running an earlier version that doesn't have the `-d` flag.

Answer (score 2):

There was a problem with `inotifywait` version. While v3.14 has `-d` and `-o` parameters, **older version 3.13 hasn't**.

This can solve that:

```
#!/bin/bash
inotifywait -qmr -e modify,delete,delete_self,create,moved_from,moved_to /path |
while read line; do
        echo $line >> /tmp/watch.log
done
```

And runs with `&` at the end of command.

Comment: Can't you simply use `>>` redirection after the command? What's the loop for?

Answer (score 0):

On my system, I get a different error:

```
-o must be specified with -d
```

So ... try specifying `-o`? Or simply background it with `&` instead (in `sh`-compatible shells at least).

Comment: Yes I'm specifying `-o` and just forgot to add to the command in question I just corrected.